# How to change the color of menu bar when flutter web app installs as a PWA?

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I've created a flutter web app. When I install that app as a progressive web app from the URL then the menu bar colour is not the one specified in the manifest file.

This is the `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "short_name": "Lorem",
    "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "description": "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "/",
    "background_color": "#393557",
    "theme_color": "#393557",
    "display": "minimal-ui",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary"
}
```

This is my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Lorem ipsum">
  <meta id="flutterweb-theme" name="theme-color" content="#393557">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icons/Icon-192.png">

  <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
</head>
<body id="app-container">
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is it that's missing? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Did you managed to fix it? I'm facing the same problem!

Comment: @pitazzo No, I still couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Put this meta tag between "head" tag in index.html file.

```
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#393557">
```

It will change your mobile browser's top menu color.

Comment: gracias me funcionó perfecto!

Comment: Any solution to change the toolbar color when changing the theme from light to dark?

Comment: @AlienDecoy 
I made some sample code for the app theme structure please check it out!

https://github.com/BansookNam/fast_app_base/blob/main/lib/common/theme/custom_theme.dart
https://github.com/BansookNam/fast_app_base/blob/main/lib/common/theme/custom_theme_app.dart

Final result:
https://github.com/BansookNam/fast_app_base/blob/main/lib/app.dart